# In an open set $U$, can we always extend a disc to an open ball contained in $U$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $U$ be an open set containing $D_R(x_0) := \{x\in X : d(x, x_0)\le R\}$. Now, can we say that there will be an $R_1 > R$ such that $B_{R_1}(x_0)\subseteq U$?

If I replace $D_R(x_0)$ by $B_R(x_0)$, then it's obviously false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $D$ refers to the closed ball and $B$ refers to the open ball.
The answer is no.
Let $X$ be the set of real sequences $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ that are eventually vanishing (meaning that $x_n=0$ for $n$ large enough), equipped with the norm $\|(x_n)\| = \sup_{n}|x_n|$.
Consider the set
$$
U = \left\{(x_n)_{n \geqslant 1} \in X\mid \forall n \geqslant 1, |x_n| < 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right\},
$$
which is open in $X$.
Then the closed unit ball centred at $0$ is included in $U$, but no open ball centred at $0$ and of radius $R>1$ lies in $U$.

However, your claim is true provided that $D_R(x_0)$ is compact.

Comment: $U$ is not open. $U$ contains the sequence $s=(1,1,1, \dots)$, but no open ball centered on $s$ is included in $U$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Urgh, you might be right!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think that considering eventually vanishing sequences fixes the issue you have raised

Comment: Yes it does indeed fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not true. Here is a counterexample.

Let $R_n \subset \mathbb R^2$ denote the line through the points $p_0 = (0,0)$ and $p_n = (n,1)$. Define
$$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R_n$$
with the Euclidean metric $d(p,q) = \lVert x - y \rVert$ induced from $\mathbb R^2$. Next define
$$U_n = \{ p \in R_n \mid d(p, p_0) < 1 +1/n \}, \\ U = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n .$$
We have
$$U = B_1(p_0) \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (U_n \setminus \{p_0\}) .$$
This shows that $U$ is open in $X$ because all $U_n \setminus \{p_0\}$ are open in $X$. Clearly $D_1(p_0) \subset U$. But we have $B_r(p_o) \not\subset U$ for $r > 1$.